# Is it possible to show "current meeting attendees" via an Adaptive Card?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have somewhat of a unique use case where my team needs a 24-hour conference bridge.  To keep the Teams chat threads from getting too long, I currently re-create the conference bridge via a Flow once each month.  The Flow creates a new meeting invitation and posts an adaptive card with a "join" button that has a direct link into the current meeting.

One feature we're missing from the "meet now" or "schedule a meeting" feature in our team channel is the faces of the people that are currently present in the meeting.  Is it possible to recreate this via the adaptive card? Or, is there another way for me change to flow to maybe post a "meet now" message once per month instead of a custom adaptive card?

Please let me know if you want some more detail or if my request doesn't make sense for some reason.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a deeplink to schedule a meeting using

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new?subject=<meeting subject>&startTime=<date>&endTime=<date>&content=<content>&attendees=<user1>,<user2>,<user3>,...
```

and you can specify this as the URL target in your card's button or tap action through the `openUrl` action type. For more details please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-the-scheduling-dialog).

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.  Just to be clear, we already have a "join meeting" button posted in the adaptive card and it allows people to join the meeting just fine.  What I'm looking to do is have that same adaptive card show the profile pictures of the folks that are currently in the meeting, similar to what you would see if you clicked the "meet now" button on any given post/thread within a channel.

Comment: @ChristopherParsons Currently it's not possible get profile pictures of the participants that are currently in the meeting.

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Yea you can find out whos suposed to be in the meeting based on the appointment but cant find out whos currently in afaik.